# php code is working on its own but not inside another document

Tags: php, file, include, echo

I have some php in a file on its own called cheeseside.php

```
<?php
foreach (glob("./Cheese_of_Week/*.php") as $fileName) {  //set files in specified directory as $fileName
   $fileContents = file_get_contents($fileName); //retrieve the contents of the php file in string format
   $findme   = 'id="cheeseName'; //finds where the cheese name starts in the file
   $findme2 = '</h2>'; //find the end of the cheese name
   $pos = strpos($fileContents, $findme); //finds the offset starting position 
   $pos2 = strpos($fileContents, $findme2, $pos); //finds the ending position of the name
   $cheesePos=$pos+strlen($findme)+2; //finds the real starting position by cominsating for the search term and 2 characters of the html tag that I didn't include in the search term
   $cheeseName = substr($fileContents, $cheesePos, $pos2-$cheesePos); //Isolates the cheese name from the     $fileContents string
   if ($fileName != "./Cheese_of_Week/currentCheese.php")  //avoids repeating the current cheese which is one of the php files that will be pulled
     echo "<a href=\"$fileName\">".$cheeseName."</a>"."<br/>"; //makes a link to the the php file    
} 
?>
```

When I call the file directly, it does exactly what I want it to do (list the php files it finds as links.) When I try to call this file with an include statement from a the file called currentCheese.php, I get absolutely nothing. I have other include statements in that file that work fine. I even tried putting the code directly in the document and it won't work. I have been searching through the php.net manual pages and stack overflow to see if it has something to do with the scope, or the include statememt, or the echo. I just can't figure out why I'm getting nothing.

Comment: Are you sure your paths are correct from the currentCheese.php file?

Comment: Paths were not correct, I was searching through so much thinking that it was something complicated. What a simple thing to get hung up on!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that `glob("./Cheese_of_Week/*.php")` is relative to your *entry point*, in your case *currentCheese.php*

To make the path always relate to the location of *cheeseside.php* use:

```
glob(__DIR__ . "/Cheese_of_Week/*.php");
```

About [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: Thanks, I feel so dumb that I just wasted so much time on this. cheeseside.php was in the parent directory of Cheese_of_Week.